# Transaction in Neo4j 3.5 does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable

Tags: java, neo4j

I have installed the `community edition 3.5.0-alpha07` of `Neo4j` and I am trying to create a simple `graph` containing two nodes following [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/neo4j/neo4j_native_java_api_example.htm) tutorial. The problem is that the keyword `Transaction` from `org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction` shows `syntax error`. The code is given below :

**Operation.java**

```
import java.io.File;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Label;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Node;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Relationship;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.RelationshipType;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseFactory;

public class Operation {

    //private static final File file =new File();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        GraphDatabaseFactory dbFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
        GraphDatabaseService db= dbFactory.newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder("C:\\Users\\pritom.mazumdar\\Downloads\\neo4j-community-3.5.0-alpha07\\data\\databases\\graph.db").newGraphDatabase();
        //Transaction tx = db.beginTx();
        try (Transaction tx = db.beginTx()) {
```

> The resource type **Transaction** does not implement java.lang.AutoCloseable

```
            Node javaNode = db.createNode();
            javaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "JAVA001");
            javaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Java");
            javaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "25");
            javaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");                

            Node scalaNode = db.createNode();
            scalaNode.setProperty("TutorialID", "SCALA001");
            scalaNode.setProperty("Title", "Learn Scala");
            scalaNode.setProperty("NoOfChapters", "20");
            scalaNode.setProperty("Status", "Completed");

            Relationship relationship = javaNode.createRelationshipTo(scalaNode, (RelationshipType) Label.label("JVM_LANG"));
            relationship.setProperty("Id","1234");
            relationship.setProperty("OOPS","YES");
            relationship.setProperty("FP","YES");

            tx.success();
        } 
           System.out.println("Done successfully");

        }

    }
```

I have tried implementing `AutoCloseable` and `overriding` the `close` method, but it still doesn't work, the syntax error remians.

Comment: Something's going wrong here. I can see in the code that `org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction` does indeed extend AutoClosable, and always has.

Comment: In any case, is there any particular reason why you're testing this on an alpha build? Try 3.4.6 if you want the current version as of this time.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I downloaded the latest version of neo4j which was present in their website. I couldn't find any other community edition. Could you please provide me the link for 3.4.6

Comment: [Here's our downloads page](https://neo4j.com/download-center/#releases), click on the Community Server tab, the top of that should read "Neo4j Community Edition 3.4.6" (at this point in time), and then choose the download appropriate for whether you're using Linux/Mac or Windows.

Comment: @InverseFalcon, thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

It is because try-with-resources Only Accepts `AutoClosable` Objects. The compiler Says that `Transaction` is not an `AutoClosable`.

Comment: so then how should I write the syntax for starting a transaction?

Comment: @PritomMazumdar Define the Object Outside the try block. Then, move the code Outside the Try Loop or Catch an Exemption.

Comment: the `Transaction` code has to be inside the `try` block as written in the docs of `neo4j`, also I tried catching an exception but didn't work.

Comment: @PritomMazumdar Try Moving `System.out.println("Done successfully");` Into a  'finally' Block

Comment: moving `System.out.println` statement, won't fix my problem because the syntax for `Transaction` statement shows an error. Might be coz of the apha version of neo4j

Comment: @PritomMazumdar Agree